# Why one of the columns of my SQL table cannot be extracted (a text column)?

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

When I am trying to extract one of the columns(containing text) of a table in MySQL I am getting an syntax error:

> Unexpected key_sym while it is not the case for other columns.

Anyone has an idea what the problem would be?

I am trying this simple code:

```
SELECT key, name 
FROM data1.info
```

If I  replace column "key" with any other column names it would work but not for this one.

The key column contains something like this as for keys:

```
8997897986575625757576557576523686812638612836263816283618263861826361836
```

Comment: show us the database structure and some code so we will be able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`key`is a reserved word so you have to use backticks(`) around column names when you use reserved words

```
SELECT `key`,name FROM data1.info
```

[A list of reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: I have tried this as well. With this I only get rows with the word(key) in them

Comment: @user2058811 - You must have been using single quotes not back-ticks.

Comment: Yes I am using 'key' and the result is :key
key
key
key
key
key
key
key
key
key
key
key

Comment: @user2058811, back-ticks are not the same as single quotes (the ones you are using) just copy it from the answer and try it then.